# Is listening on a port on the localhost of a server the same as listening on that port of the server's public IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, localhost, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I set up a free Amazon EC2 instance in order to use a Node app outside of my localhost environment.

The instance is allocated a public IP address at launch, mine for example being 54.187.31.42. Does this mean that if, within my launched Node program on the EC2, I'm listening for connections at `http://localhost:8080`, the server is listening for the connections at `54.187.31.42:8080` ?

Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, listening sockets on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1` or `::1` on IPv6-enabled systems) are only accessible from the very same system they were created on.

To configure a program to listen on all interfaces, you'd usually use `0.0.0.0` or `::`. According to a quick Google search this should also be valid for node.js.

Comment: Note that it's often considered best practices to _not_ use `0.0.0.0`/`::`, as the are frequently not "future-proof". That said, though, better than 9 times out of 10 it isn't really a problem, just keep it in mind if you later add a second IP and then wonder why a second web server can't start up on it.

Comment: That’s certainly true. However, for dynamic IP setups like EC2, there’s simply no other easy way.

Comment: Also it's worth to mention that if your app is configured to listen on `0.0.0.0`, there still can be firewalls, like iptables which block the port for the outside world, or in your case, there is definitely a firewall between your EC2 instance and the outside world, in which you have to enable forwarding to the port in the Amazon management console.